# Qt : Tooltip on wrong input

Tags: qt, user-interface, tooltip, qlineedit

I have a QLineEdit, on which I have set a QRegExpValidator, that allows the user to input only one whitespace between words.
Now I want that whenever the user tries to enter more than one whitespaces, the tooltip of the QLineEdit should show up, but I'm not getting any method to implement it.

Thanx :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems there is no direct method to perform what you want. One way to do above is to handle **`QLineEdit`**'s **`textChanged()` signal**. Then you can check that string against your regular expression using **`QRegExp::exactMatch()`** function and if it don't match then show tooltip.

Connect the signal..

```
...    
connect(ui->lineEdit,SIGNAL(textChanged(QString)),this,SLOT(onTextChanged(QString)));
...
```

Here your slot goes..

```
void MainWindow::onTextChanged(QString text)
{
    QRegExp regExp;
    regExp.setPattern("[^0-9]*");  // For example I have taken simpler regex..

    if(regExp.exactMatch(text))
    {
        m_correctText = text;    // Correct text so far..
        QToolTip::hideText();
    }
    else
    {
        QPoint point = QPoint(geometry().left() + ui->lineEdit->geometry().left(),
                              geometry().top() + ui->lineEdit->geometry().bottom());

        ui->lineEdit->setText(m_correctText);   // Reset previous text..
        QToolTip::showText(point,"Cannot enter number..");
    }
}
```

Comment: I got your idea, but there would be two problems with this approach:  
  1) I'm using a QRegExpValidator, which means that I don't want the user to input any invalid string, while using your approach, the user will be able to enter invalid input  


2) I don't know how to programmatically show tooltip :D

Comment: @Jaydeep: That can be solved, you can always store the correct string in another variable say `m_correctText`. Whenever regex match fails, you reset using `QLineEdit::setText(m_correctText)`.. Ya regarding the tooltip [check this](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7-snapshot/widgets-tooltips.html).. Or another suggestion would be to show `QLabel` with red text, positioned at right-side of `QLineEdit` control. :)

Comment: @Jaydeep: I have updated my answer by adding working example code.. :)

Comment: this is kinda what I wanted, but I get it..
Now i'll be able to make it work in my app...
Thanks !!

Answer (score 0):

I don't remember explicit API for showing a tooltip. I'm afraid you'll have to go with popping up a custom tool window (i.e. a parent-less `QWidget`) to achieve the desired result.

If you want to style your own popup window like a standard tooltip, `QStyle` should have something for that. If in doubt, read into the Qt source code where it renders the tooltip. That'll tell you which style elements to use.